# React Progressive Load - Loaded Images load a bit a time despite onLoad() firing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, framer-motion

**Context**
I'm attempting to make a functional component named `ProgressiveBackgroundImg`. The idea is that the background of the image will initially display a low-res image while the full-res image loads in the background. Upon the full-res loading, the new element will be displayed. I am utilising framer motion with `<AnimatePresence>` to try and transition between these two element, such that the new element doesn't just suddenly 'flash' in. An intersectionObserver is used to change `InView` which is then listened to by a `useEffect`. When this changes, the full-res image is loaded, and on load this triggers a state component tracking the image source to use termed `imgSrc` to change to the url of the full-res image.

**Problem**
The animations appear to work for the placeholder image which fades in and out. However the full-res element will be rendered immediately, while the image is still unloaded. This means it stays black (making the fade-in animation useless), and then renders in one chunk at a time. I.e. it starts off black and loads one bit at a time from the top down. Similar to [this](https://pressupinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/slow-loading-image.gif).

I'm using the Image.onLoad() function to update my local state `imgSrc` which is used in a conditional render within the component. This conditional renders an element displaying the placeholder if this `imgSrc` is equal to the placeholder prop passed in, otherwise it renders an element with the full-res image.

**Code**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { InView, useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion"]

const ProgressiveBackgroundImg = ({ placeholderSrc, src, ...props }) => {
    const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(placeholderSrc || src);
    const { ref, inView } = useInView({
        triggerOnce: true,
        rootMargin: '0px 0px'
    });


    const placeholderVariants ={
        initial: {
            opacity: 1,
        },
        animate: {
            opacity: 1
        },
        exit: {
            opacity: 0,
            transition: {
                duration: 0.45,
                ease: [0.33, 1, 0.68, 1]
            }
        }
    }

    const fullImgVariants ={
        initial: {
          opacity: 0,
        },
        animate: {
            opacity: 1,
            transition: {
                duration: 0.45,
                ease: [0.33, 1, 0.68, 1]
            }
        },
        exit: {
            opacity: 0,
            transition: {
                duration: 0.45,
                ease: [0.33, 1, 0.68, 1]
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inView){
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = src;
            img.onload = () => {
                setImgSrc(src);
            };
        }
    }, [src, inView]);

    return (
        <div ref={ref} className="grid-item__thumb">
            <AnimatePresence>
            {
                imgSrc === placeholderSrc ?
                    <motion.div 
                        initial="initial"
                        animate="animate"
                        exit="exit"
                        variants={placeholderVariants}
                        key={"tester"+imgSrc}
                        className="gi-background active"
                        style={{
                            backgroundImage: "url(".concat(imgSrc, ")")
                        }}
                    />
                :
                    <motion.div 
                        initial="initial"
                        animate="animate"
                        exit="exit"
                        variants={fullImgVariants}
                        key={"tester2"+imgSrc+"2"}
                        className="gi-background active"
                        style={{
                            backgroundImage: "url(".concat(imgSrc, ")")
                        }}
                    />    
            }
            </AnimatePresence>
        </div>
    );
  };
  export default ProgressiveBackgroundImg;
```

**Question**
My understanding is that the image being loaded into the `Image()` object doesn't mean that the dom element receiving the full-res source as a background image will be able to load and render this immediately. Essentially just loading it into an Image object then having to reload into a different one.
Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying here? I.e by using this Image() object as a background image, preventing re-loading it for the dom element, or directly listen to the full-res element to see when it has actually loaded the image and *only then* render it to the page?